# correct text input to next activity

Tags: java, android, input, android-activity, passwords

I am a completely new programmer and I am looking to make a sort of quiz app as my first app. Just Questions with the right answer that will send the user to the next activity. I figured out how to edit buttons but I am not sure what to add to the JAVA file or XML file that will allow the next activity (screen) to be opened up.

This is my Layout so far. I have decided the password input but the answer to the question will be stored within the app. Not sure if this is the right approach?

`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Question" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

 <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:text="Answer" />
```

`

Thanks in advance for any help rendered!

@kanwaljit Sngh

I am getting multiple errors like "button cannot be resolved to a type" and "R cannot be resolved to a variable" What does these mean?

`import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Startscreen extends Activity {

```
  EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String answer = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
                if (answer.equals("desired answer")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            CorrectAnswerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            WrongAnswerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }

    });
```

`

Comment: While click the button, you can check for right answer is equal to input value of edit text. If it true then you start your next activity or else shown message to user(your answer was wrong)

Comment: If you need to send some data from one activity to another you should use Intent's Bundle. Also you could use SharedPrefs to store your data and to load it any time you want like in another activity.

Comment: May be it will useful for you: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-ui-workshop-build-an-interactive-quiz-app--mobile-14208

Comment: You using any database to store your question and options?

Comment: Nope, just text displays and the validation of edittext works for me. I cant seem to implement the code. Its throwing multiple errors.

Comment: Can you post your complete xml layout and source for your activity?

Comment: Its not letting me edit my post further. Haha oh man, makes me frustrated knowing that there is so much about computers that I dont know about.... Basically my android manifest xml file is just normal consisting of the version number, uses-sdk and <application that is all

Answer (score 1):

1. [Get the value of edittext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29)
2. check it with desired answer
3. If true, redirect to next activity

Eg :

```
  if(editText1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("desiredanswer")
  {
               startActivity(new Intent(this,nextActivity.class));
  }
  else
  {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Wrong answer",2000).show();
  }
```

Comment: Do I need to add anything to the XML file?

Comment: No u need to add click listner for the button in java file

Answer (score 0):

```
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String answer = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
                if (answer.equals("desired answer")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            CorrectAnswerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            WrongAnswerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }

    });
```

and write new two activity CorrectAnswerActivty and WrongAnswerActivity 
and do actions what to display in these activties
and add the following line to the xml file in `button` tag-

```
android:id="@+id/button"
```